# .htaccess mass link redirect to new urls

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I'm trying to upgrade my website and in my new website the whole linking system is different, I wanted to ask if its possible to redirect my old urls to new urls?

**/1 Old Link**

http://example.com/1/computers/12/32/4003_apple_iphone_xr_reviews.html

In this old link I need the product id which is "4003" in the example and the product name which comes after it.

**/1 New Link is like this**

http://example.com/computers/4003/apple_iphone_xr_reviews

**/2 Old Link**

http://example.com/1/category/3/32_mobile_phones/

In this one I need the first number is always 1 which comes at the end of the link and I need the category id which is "32" in the example and the name of category which comes after it...

**/2 New Link is like this**

http://example.com/category/32/show/mobile_phones/1

Comment: It's definitely possible using [`mod_rewrite`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/intro.html). Take a look and give it a try.

Comment: @Jeto I did but I couldn't find a solution...

Comment: So the question is: _why_ can't you find a solution? You will need to tell us what you tried and what _specific_ issues you ran into. How else do you expect us to be able to help with those attempts?